# UNIX command on Windows using Git Bash -- Error: "'C:\Program' is not recognized"

Tags: windows, bash, git

I just installed Git bash in order to run a UNIX command. I am trying to recreate a project starter which is using UNIX; it seemed there was no way for Windows to run a "grep" command without using something like Git bash.

1. I CD into the project folder directory

   `mboyl@DESKTOP-8R019P7 MINGW64 ~/lei_broker (master)`
2. Then I run my command

   `$ heroku config:set SANITY_READ_TOKEN=$(grep SANITY_READ_TOKEN .env.development)`
3. And am met with the error

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What is going on here? **'C:\Program' is not included in my command.**

My initial troubleshooting has recommended using a shell besides Git bash or setting an environment variable. My technical chops are limited, so if there is a simple Linux/UNIX syntax error I am making, please advise.

- Matt

Comment: That error looks like it came from window's CMD, not bash.

Comment: One does not install git to run Unix commands so your statement does not make sense. You also tagged this with Linux but Linux is not Unix.

Comment: Someone forgot to put their path to file within quotes

Comment: Commands are executables, stored in a directory somewhere.  Your grep command is somewhere on your system (if it is installed at all!).  Specify the complete path to grep to ensure it will be found.  NOTE: git bash is not a full linux environment!  Look into installing the Linux Subsystem for Windows to get all commands and utilities.

Comment: A decent guess is heroku is not well behaved under cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting as an answer since I need 50 Reps.*
While I don't know what's inside the file .env.development, why not wrap all Windows paths with single-quotes & try?